# Comparing Multiple File Types in an if Statement

Tags: matlab

I am importing a file into a function using `[filepath, name, ext]=fileparts(thisFile);`. I would then like to use a series of if statements that will operate on the file depending on its type; however, come files will have the same initial set up and so I would like to be able to include them all in an if statement. My current implementation: `elseif (ext == '.s3p')`. If I put in something like: `elseif (ext == '.s2p' || '.s3p')` the compiler whines,

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

You see my logic. Is there anything that I can do to make this work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably want [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), not `==`. With `a==b` you get *element-wise* comparison. So you get a logical vector as result; and if `a` and `b` have different number of characters you get an error.
2. The fact that the output of `==` is a logical *vector* of element-wise comparisons is what causes the m-lint message. `||` and `&&` require *scalar* arguments.
3. Lastly, in `(ext == '.s2p' || '.s3p')` you probably meant `(ext == '.s2p' || ext == '.s3p')`.

Combining all of the above:

```
elseif strcmp(ext,'.s2p') || strcmp(ext,'.s3p')
```

For clarity and readability, you may prefer to use the [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function with a cell array of the extensions to compare with:

```
elseif ismember(ext, {'.s2p' ,'.s3p'})
```

or, as pointed out by Cris Luengo,

```
elseif any(strcmp(ext, {'.s2p', '.s3p'}))
```

Better yet, instead of a series of `elseif` statements you may prefer to use [`switch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html), which implicitly applies `strcmp` / `ismember` for each `case`:

```
switch ext
    case {'sp2', 'sp3'}
        % Do stuff
    case {'aaa', 'bbb'}
        % Do stuff
    otherwise
        error('Unrecognized extension')
end
```

Comment: `ismember` is interesting, I've always done `any(strcmp(ext,{'.s2p','.s3p'}))`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I hadn't thought of that. I added it as an alternative